# Create an order with nested attributes in CommerceTools

Tags: commercetools

I want to create an order that has the following representation

```
{   
   /* basic order fields ... */
   // additional order fields 
    "destination": {
        "id": "000",
        "name": "xxx",
        "country": "AB"
    },
    "origin": {
        "id": "111",
        "name": "YYY",
        "country": "CD"
    },
    "account": {
        "holder": {
            "name": "name exampel",
            "gender": "gender example",
            "preferredCity": "some city"
        },
        "saldo": 30
    }
}
```

The docs show how we can create order types, which is fine if the fields have flat representation, but in my case I need to have some levels of nesting. I thought about creating the inner types first and then using them in the containing type until I reach root, but it didnt work for me.

What is the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no order type but you can create custom types (with custom fields) on the order object. https://docs.commercetools.com/api/projects/orders#representations

For the supported field types you can have a look here: https://docs.commercetools.com/api/projects/types#fieldtype

Have you looked into type set or reference yet?
With type reference you could link to a custom object (key-value-document) where you can store JSON formatted data as you need. https://docs.commercetools.com/api/projects/custom-objects#customobject

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer! I did indeed read through the docs! The idea I understood from the key-value-document is to be used when the data is loosely typed and quite random! But the data I have is structured and typed! Would it be possible to show how I can achieve my target type to use for an order?